# Can a loop create a new, different array each time it runs?

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I want to create a loop in C that will generate a new, different array each time it runs. Can this be done? And if so, how?

Something along the lines of:

```
int main()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
     int arrayi[5] = {0};
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The intended behavior is to then have 10 arrays, called array1, array2, array3, array4, array5, array6, array7, array8, array9, array10; each holding 5 elements, and each element being 0.

Comment: If you need 10 arrays, you need to define 10 arrays. Or an array of 10 arrays.

Comment: You now about arrays. They provide int0, int1, int2, ... Now compare that to your question. What you want is an array of arrays, or a 2D array, isn't it?

Comment: How are you intending to use said arrays?

Comment: You *do* get a new, different array in each iteration of that loop, as far as C is concerned.  And the lifetime of each one ends at the end of its iteration.  If you want arrays with longer lifetime then they need to have broader scope or allocated duration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on what exactly you want to do. In your example, you will create 10 individual and seperate arrays, but maybe their use is not so helpful because:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  int arrayi[5] = {0};  // The array is created here.
} // The array goes out of scope and is destroyed here. It can't be used in the next
  // iteration of the for loop.
// You can't use any of the arrays created here.
```

Maybe this is what you want, if you want to use the array in the for loop for example.

Maybe you want the array to stick around so you can use it after. Then you have 2 choices:

1. Make a 2d array:

---

```
int arr[10][5]; // Use by indexing eg arr[4][1] is the second 
                // element of the fifth array.
// or
int arr[50]; // A flat packed array, usually accessed via 
             // index: row*rowlength + colomn
```

2. Define each of the arrays as a seperate named object (**very rare** that this is required):

---

```
int arrForUse[5];
int arrForDifferentUse[7];
...
int arrXXX[15];
```

If the arrays are truely used for different things and are not related at all this is what you will do. They will not be named `arr1`, `arr2`, ... though.

Comment: The "make a bunch of array variables" approach is not programming, it's against the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) and just makes a gigantic mess of things. The 2D array approach is the answer.

Comment: @tadman I have made it more clear, but the point was that they are for different purposes, not similar variables that could be in an array. If they are for unrelated purposes and they are limited and the amount of them is not decided at run time then this approach is ok.

Comment: If they're for entirely different purposes, then *perhaps*. Usually a mess of variables like that is a good way to dig a very deep hole for yourself. What this code probably needs is a generator function that can allocate, populate, and return a pointer to an array of some arbitrary size. These static-length arrays are going to be trouble to pass around.

Comment: @tadman I guess the example i am thinking of is the kinematics of a robot. In a six axis robot kinematic calculation you may have a series of arrays that store different data and are of different length. In an inverse kinematic function for a 6 axis robot you would see this type of arrays. This might be the same in other fields like karmen filters etc. It is rare, which is why i bolded **rarely**.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but it also means that point #2 is the important one and point #1 is basically a "you'll probably never need this code", so I'm questioning why #1 is given prominence. State the best practice first, the edge cases second, that's all.

Comment: @tadman You are right. I swapped them and made the rareity point more prominant.

Answer (score 1):

```
arrayi[5]
```

What you probably want is this array[i][j].
If i understood your question correctly you would need something like this:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
   {
     array[i][j] = /*use some random function like rand()*/;
   }
```

Comment: Yeah, i meant without the "int". Making array global.

Answer (score 0):

You can not literraly replace a character in a variable name using a loop. E.g. the `i` in `arrayi` can not be replaced by a loop or anything else!

What you need to do is to either:

- Declare arrays before, and fill them with a loop
- Declare a single 2D array and then in loops `malloc` and fill each position with pointer to those `malloced` arrays.

Answer (score -1):

If the array is huge you may consider use of the `malloc` family functions.

Comment: I'm not sure what definition of huge you're using, but 10x5 `int` array is not huge.

Comment: Array size in MBs

Comment: The original question makes no mention of megabytes. It's literally 10 arrays of 5 `int` elements. That's 400 bytes. Not megabytes.